# SwiftUI MVVM pattern applied correctly?

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I am not sure if I applied the MVVM pattern correctly to my situation.
Can you please give me some feedback if there is something wrong or can be improved?

Entry point is the `App` struct, which creates the `Router` and the `PageService`.
These instances are passed to all views as environment objects.

```
@main
struct App: App {
    var router = Router()
    var pageService = PageService()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
                .environmentObject(router)
                .environmentObject(pageService)
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside my `RootView` I create a `TabBarView` which contains some `TabBarItemViews`.
The code below shows my setup (I removed the unimportant stuff and hopefully not more):

```
struct RootView: View {    
    @EnvironmentObject var pageService: PageService
    
    var body: some View {
        TabBarView(vm: TabBarViewModel(pageService: pageService))
    }
}
```

```
struct TabBarView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: TabBarViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(self.vm.tabs, id: \.id) { tab in
            TabBarItemView(vm: tab)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class TabBarViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabs = [TabBarItemViewModel]()
    var pageService: PageService
        
    init(pageService: PageService) {
        self.pageService = pageService
        self.tabs = self.pageService.fetchPages()
            .map(TabBarItemViewModel.init)
    }
}
```

```
struct TabBarItemView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: Router
    @StateObject var vm: TabBarItemViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(self.vm.id))
        // using router to show selected item highlighted etc
    }
}
```

```
class TabBarItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var page: Page
        
    init(_ page: Page) {
        self.page = page
    }
        
    var id: Int {
        return self.page.id
    }
}
```

Is the location of the ViewModels creation including the PageService injection correct?
Is there a way to create the TabBarViewModel inside the View and inject the PageService?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views, their view (state, business logic etc) models and the app data models all appear nicely separated, so fwiw the example looks good to me - especially if the full code is working :-)

In terms of MVVM refinement; I've seen it suggested that:

- Putting the view models in an extension of their view is sensible - since they are almost never reused anywhere else and it makes organisation a bit easier.
- Using Protocols to specify model parameters is a good practice as it permits more flexibility, particularly with regards to the use of mock objects during testing.

For more details on the above, Kilo Loco's short YouTube video on the subject is good, it can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdqEcpppAMc&list=LL&index=2&t=880s)

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the improvements.